# python mysql insert with variables

Tags: python, mysql

I have coule problems with code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import smbus
import time
import sys
import MySQLdb
import threading


from ctypes import c_short
from ctypes import c_byte
from ctypes import c_ubyte
from threading import Thread

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="", user="",passwd="", db="")
curs = db.cursor()



DEVICE = 0x77 # Default device I2C address


bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Rev 2 Pi, Pi 2 & Pi 3 uses bus 1
                     # Rev 1 Pi uses bus 0

def getShort(data, index):
  # return two bytes from data as a signed 16-bit value
  return c_short((data[index+1] << 8) + data[index]).value

def getUShort(data, index):
  # return two bytes from data as an unsigned 16-bit value
  return (data[index+1] << 8) + data[index]

def getChar(data,index):
  # return one byte from data as a signed char
  result = data[index]
  if result > 127:
    result -= 256
  return result

def getUChar(data,index):
  # return one byte from data as an unsigned char
  result =  data[index] & 0xFF
  return result

def readBME280ID(addr=DEVICE):
  # Chip ID Register Address
  REG_ID     = 0xD0
  (chip_id, chip_version) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_ID, 2)
  return (chip_id, chip_version)

def readBME280All(addr=DEVICE):
  # Register Addresses
  REG_DATA = 0xF7
  REG_CONTROL = 0xF4
  REG_CONFIG  = 0xF5

  REG_CONTROL_HUM = 0xF2
  REG_HUM_MSB = 0xFD
  REG_HUM_LSB = 0xFE

  # Oversample setting - page 27
  OVERSAMPLE_TEMP = 2
  OVERSAMPLE_PRES = 2
  MODE = 1

  # Oversample setting for humidity register - page 26
  OVERSAMPLE_HUM = 2
  bus.write_byte_data(addr, REG_CONTROL_HUM, OVERSAMPLE_HUM)

  control = OVERSAMPLE_TEMP<<5 | OVERSAMPLE_PRES<<2 | MODE
  bus.write_byte_data(addr, REG_CONTROL, control)

  # Read blocks of calibration data from EEPROM
  # See Page 22 data sheet
  cal1 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, 0x88, 24)
  cal2 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, 0xA1, 1)
  cal3 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, 0xE1, 7)

  # Convert byte data to word values
  dig_T1 = getUShort(cal1, 0)
  dig_T2 = getShort(cal1, 2)
  dig_T3 = getShort(cal1, 4)

  dig_P1 = getUShort(cal1, 6)
  dig_P2 = getShort(cal1, 8)
  dig_P3 = getShort(cal1, 10)
  dig_P4 = getShort(cal1, 12)
  dig_P5 = getShort(cal1, 14)
  dig_P6 = getShort(cal1, 16)
  dig_P7 = getShort(cal1, 18)
  dig_P8 = getShort(cal1, 20)
  dig_P9 = getShort(cal1, 22)

  dig_H1 = getUChar(cal2, 0)
  dig_H2 = getShort(cal3, 0)
  dig_H3 = getUChar(cal3, 2)

  dig_H4 = getChar(cal3, 3)
  dig_H4 = (dig_H4 << 24) >> 20
  dig_H4 = dig_H4 | (getChar(cal3, 4) & 0x0F)

  dig_H5 = getChar(cal3, 5)
  dig_H5 = (dig_H5 << 24) >> 20
  dig_H5 = dig_H5 | (getUChar(cal3, 4) >> 4 & 0x0F)

  dig_H6 = getChar(cal3, 6)

  # Wait in ms (Datasheet Appendix B: Measurement time and current calculation)
  wait_time = 1.25 + (2.3 * OVERSAMPLE_TEMP) + ((2.3 * OVERSAMPLE_PRES) + 0.575) + ((2.3 * OVERSAMPLE_HUM)+0.575)
  time.sleep(wait_time/1000)  # Wait the required time  

  # Read temperature/pressure/humidity
  data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_DATA, 8)
  pres_raw = (data[0] << 12) | (data[1] << 4) | (data[2] >> 4)
  temp_raw = (data[3] << 12) | (data[4] << 4) | (data[5] >> 4)
  hum_raw = (data[6] << 8) | data[7]

  #Refine temperature
  var1 = ((((temp_raw>>3)-(dig_T1<<1)))*(dig_T2)) >> 11
  var2 = (((((temp_raw>>4) - (dig_T1)) * ((temp_raw>>4) - (dig_T1))) >> 12) * (dig_T3)) >> 14
  t_fine = var1+var2
  temperature = float(((t_fine * 5) + 128) >> 8);

  # Refine pressure and adjust for temperature
  var1 = t_fine / 2.0 - 64000.0
  var2 = var1 * var1 * dig_P6 / 32768.0
  var2 = var2 + var1 * dig_P5 * 2.0
  var2 = var2 / 4.0 + dig_P4 * 65536.0
  var1 = (dig_P3 * var1 * var1 / 524288.0 + dig_P2 * var1) / 524288.0
  var1 = (1.0 + var1 / 32768.0) * dig_P1
  if var1 == 0:
    pressure=0
  else:
    pressure = 1048576.0 - pres_raw
    pressure = ((pressure - var2 / 4096.0) * 6250.0) / var1
    var1 = dig_P9 * pressure * pressure / 2147483648.0
    var2 = pressure * dig_P8 / 32768.0
    pressure = pressure + (var1 + var2 + dig_P7) / 16.0

  # Refine humidity
  humidity = t_fine - 76800.0
  humidity = (hum_raw - (dig_H4 * 64.0 + dig_H5 / 16384.0 * humidity)) * (dig_H2 / 65536.0 * (1.0 + dig_H6 / 67108864.0 * humidity * (1.0 + dig_H3 / 67108864.0 * humidity)))
  humidity = humidity * (1.0 - dig_H1 * humidity / 524288.0)
  if humidity > 100:
    humidity = 100
  elif humidity < 0:
    humidity = 0

  return temperature/100.0,pressure/100.0,humidity

def main():



  threading.Timer(10.0, main).start()

  (chip_id, chip_version) = readBME280ID()
  print "Chip ID     :", chip_id
  print "Version     :", chip_version


  temperature,pressure,humidity = readBME280All()



  print "Temperature : ", temperature, "C"
  print "Pressure : ", pressure, "hPa"
  print "Humidity : ", humidity, "%"

  params = urllib.urlencode({'key': '',
                             'field1': str(temperature),
                             'field2': str(pressure),
                             'field3': str(humidity)})
  try:
    f = urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update", data=params)
    print f.read()
  except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    pass




def testsql():  
  threading.Timer(1.0, testsql).start()
  (chip_id, chip_version) = readBME280ID() 
  temperature,pressure,humidity = readBME280All()
  print "Temperature : ", temperature, "C"

sql = "INSERT INTO data (day, time, temperature, pressure, humidity) values (CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), %s , %s, %s)"

curs.execute(sql, (temperature,pressure,humidity))  



if __name__=="__main__":

    Thread(target = main).start()
    Thread(target = testsql).start()
```

1) problem that mysql doesn't update every second, only once at start
2) I cant use variables, i get error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "script.py", line 212, in 
            curs.execute(sql, (temperature))
        NameError: name 'temperature' is not defined

For importing i tryed different solutions, but no any hope anymore that I  can do it myself

Answer (score 0):

After the definition of `testsql`, the `sql` variable assignment and cursor execution aren't indented and are part of the top-level code block.  Thus they are executed when the module is loaded and they can't see the `temperature` variable which is local to `testsql`.

Comment: The first my project in phyton, the theoiry I undendestand, but what syntax need to be?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) gives some good detail on scoping and blocks.  

Note that there are other issues with the code (such as the fact that you execute the SQL but don't capture the iterator returned.  You'll probably want to break out the individual functions and troubleshoot in a divide-and-conquer approach.  Trying to debug code in 200-line chunks is a challenge for anyone.